# Let X = (0,1) ∪ {2} and let d7: X x X->[0,∞+) be a function defined

Tags: metric-spaces

In topology,Let $X = (0,1) ∪ \{2\}$ and let $d_7: X \times X\to [0,∞)$ be a function defined formulas:
$$
d_7(x,y)=\cases{|x-y| & if $x ∈ (0,1)$ and $y ∈ (0,1)$\\7 & if $x=2$ and $y ∈(0,1)$\\ 7& if $x ∈(0,1)$ and $y=2$\\0& if $x=2$ and $y=2$}
$$
Please check if $d_7$ is a distance function on $X$.

Does anybody explain and solve this question ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE! Please provide some context so that users know how best to help you with this. If you show some of your own thoughts, even (especially) ones resulting in dead ends, this will help users steer you in the right direction, and properly address your question at your level of understanding the subject. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $d_7$ is a distance function, because for each $x,y,z\in X$ we have $d_7(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$, $d_7(x,y)=d_7(y,x)$, and $d_7(x,z)\le d_7(x,y)+d_7 (y,z)$. The first two properties are easy to check while looking at the definition on $d_7$. The last inequality clearly holds when $x,y,z\in (0,1)$, because then it is the triangle inequality for the standard distance on $\Bbb R$. If $d_7(x,y)=7$ or $d_7(y,z)=7$ then the inequality holds, because anyway $d_7(x,z)\le 7$. The remaining case is $x=y=z=2$, in which the inequality holds trivially.

---

We have to show that $d_7(x,y)+d_7 (y,z)\ge d_7(x,z)$ for each $x,y,z\in X$. The following cases are possible.

1) $x,y,z\in (0,1)$. Then  $d_7(x,z)=|x-z|$,  $d_7(x,y)=|x-y|$, and $d_7(y,z)=|y-z|$. Then  $d_7(x,z)\le d_7(x,y)+d_7 (y,z)$ because $|a|+|b|\ge |a+b| $ for all real $a$ and $b$, so $$|x-y|+|y-z|\ge |(x-y)+(y-z)|=|x-z|.$$

2) $x\in (0,1)$, $y=2$ or $y\in (0,1)$, $x=2$. Then  $d_7(x,y)+d_7(y,z)\ge d_7(x,y)=7\ge d_7(x,z)$.

3) $z\in (0,1)$, $y=2$ or $y\in (0,1)$, $z=2$. Then  $d_7(x,y)+d_7(y,z)\ge d_7(y,z)=7\ge d_7(x,z)$.

4) $x=y=z=2$. Then   $d_7(x,y)+d_7(y,z)=0+0=0=d_7(x,z)$.

Comment: Could you giving more then clearly details by formally ? and writing all possible cases....This is so significant to me like as e.g 1) x,y,z ∈ (0,1) 2) d7(y,z)=7 for clearly and formally solutions ? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ArdaBatuhanDemir Done.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Can you look up this question ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067642/in-topology-find-all-points-of-the-set-b-2-2-1-1-0-1-0-3-which-are/3067699#3067699